# "I wish I would wake up early"

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs, wish-preterite

Is this sentence correct?

> I wish I would wake up early

Some grammar rules say that *would* shouldn't be used when its subject is the same as *wish* subject. It ‘would be illogical’, the rule says.

I came across this sentence which seems to break the rule. What is the reason?

Comment: Depends. If you wish you yourself were able to wake up every day at a specific time, then use could. If you have some plans and you hope you will wake up in time, use would

Comment: So, does 'wish' equal 'hope' and can be used to express plans?

Comment: Where are these grammar rules from? "Some grammar rules" is very unspecific, yet at the same time you seem to be actually quoting them, so please go ahead and straight out attribute them. Also, do state the supposedly grammatical alternative to this sentence, according to the rules in question. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

We can use *wish* + *subject* + *past tense* to express regret that a present situation is not how we want it:

> I wish I had a car. = I don't have a car.
>
> I wish I knew the answer. = I don't know the answer.
>
> I wish I woke up early. = I don't wake up early.

We use *wish* + *subject* + *would* to express regret about an action that a third party is unwilling to perform.

> I wish she would go home now. = I am sorry that she isn't willing to
>   go home.
>
> I wish he would get a haircut. = I am sorry that he refuses to get a
>   haircut.

It would be strange to say:

> I wish I would go home now

or

> I wish I would get a haircut.

because I have the power to perform those actions if I want. This is why Thomson and Martinet in *Practical English Grammar* (p262) state:

> The subject of *wish* cannot be the same as the subject of *would* as this
>   would be illogical. We cannot therefore have **I wish** + **I would**.

The example sentence is somewhat different because the speaker is not expressing regret over a *unwillingness* to wake up early but over an *inability* to do so. In this case, *I wish I would wake up early* seems acceptable to me. But I prefer:

> I wish I woke up early

or

> I wish I could wake up early.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.You spoke for me. Actually, the book you quoted is my reference, but the topic is on (p 202), second edition.Still, what makes you say,'In this case, I wish I would wake up early seems acceptable to me. But I prefer:'?Is it a matter of opinion, or does it have a reference? If interpretation is allowed loosely,then the first rule is useless.

Comment: Thomson and Martinet's (fourth edition) examples in the section you refer to concern willingness, but your example sentence is about ability. So the rule does not necessarily apply. I'd be interested in the opinion of other site regulars as to the acceptability of your sentence.

Comment: @Shoe How about _I wish I would win the lottery_? Where _I wish I could win the lottery_ implies a possibility of winning the lottery (ie if you buy the right number of tickets or the right ticket you could win) but the _would_ in _I wish I would win the lottery._ implies the will  to win the lottery despite your failing attempts. A more verbose  _I wish I would win the [next] lottery._

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that "?I wish I would wake up early" is a good English sentence.

Here's what's wrong with it. Both *wish* and *would* let you describe an event that isn't real. You simply don't need "would" if you say "I wish I woke up early." A principle of *pragmatics* (the study of how we use context to communicate) is that we don't say things we don't need to say. So when you say "I wish I would wake up early" the listener immediately wonders why you needed the extra word. For me at least, it leads to a brief speculation that for some reason the speaker is not in control--trapped in a dream or something.

Answer (score 0):

However, *would* also may imply a habit.  So, "I wish I woke up early" may be said of a particular past situation (say, yesterday, because I missed the bus), whereas "I wish I would wake up early" may be said regarding my bad habit of always sleeping too late.